# Was bedeutet "vor Sorge weder ein noch aus wissen"?

Tags: meaning, etymology, german-to-english

In dem Artikel ["Wer diesen Satz lesen kann, hat gute Eltern"](http://www.spiegel.de/politik/deutschland/leseschwache-schueler-die-neue-klassengesellschaft-a-1183282.html) bin ich folgender Redewendung(?) begegnet, aber die Bedeutung ist mir nicht ganz klar.

> Was also soll man tun? Das Erste wäre die Einsicht, dass man es mit
>   Strukturen zu tun hat, die sich der Sozialingenieurskunst entziehen.
>   Wir haben uns angewöhnt, von "bildungsfernen Schichten" zu sprechen.
>   Ich halte das für einen Euphemismus. "Bildungsfern" klingt wie ein
>   unverschuldetes Schicksal, dabei ist es genau das nicht. Es mag die
>   Alleinerziehende geben, **die vor Sorge weder ein noch aus weiß**, und
>   deshalb abends zu müde ist, um noch ein Buch zur Hand zu nehmen. Aber
>   das erklärt nicht die Zahl der Zehnjährigen mit gravierenden
>   Leseschwächen.

Was ist die Funktion von "ein" und "aus"? Sind die Präfixe von "wissen"?

Comment: Eine gute Webseite für Redewendungen ist [https://www.redensarten-index.de](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=weder+ein+noch+aus+wissen&bool=relevanz&gawoe=an&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou)

Comment: Nach Übersetzungen auf Englisch solltest du auf https://english.stackexchange.com fragen, und nach Übersetzungen auf Russisch auf https://russian.stackexchange.com, aber ich fürchte, dass Fragen nach Übersetzungen dort ebenso offtopic sind wie hier

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Das ist eine Redewendung, die man, wie fast alle Redewendungen, nicht so einfach eins-zu-eins in eine andere Sprache übersetzen kann. (Davon abgesehen sind Fragen, die Kenntnisse in irgendwelchen Fremdsprachen für die Beantwortung erfordern würden, hier off-topic.)

Die Redewendung bedeutet:

> Ich bin ratlos

Was die Herkunft betrifft, kann ich nur raten, ich habe bei meiner Recherche nichts brauchbares gefunden. Ich vermute folgendes:

Die Redewendung beschreibt die Situation einer Person, die sich in einer verfahrenen Situation an einer Grenze befindet. Dort, an dieser Übergangstelle zu bleiben, wäre die schlechteste Wahl. Besser wäre es, sich zurück (nach innen) oder weiter vorwärts (nach außen) zu bewegen. Aber die Person, die sich an dieser Stelle befindet, weiß weder wie sie das eine (sich nach innen bewegen) noch das andere (sich nach außen bewegen) bewerkstelligen soll.

Ich deute *»ein«* und *»aus«* also als *»hinein«* und *»hinaus«*.

> Ich weiß weder, wie man hinein, noch wie man hinaus kommt.

Ursprünglich war das vielleicht durchaus räumlich gemeint, heute wird diese Redewendung aber nur noch im übertragenen Sinn verwendet, ganz im Sinn der gleichbedeutenden, und ebenfalls existierenden Redewendung

> Ich weiß weder vor noch zurück.

Das bedeutet:

> Ich weiß weder, wie man vor, noch wie man zurück kommt.

Comment: Wenn man weder ein noch aus (oder vor noch zurück) weiß, dann steckt man fest. Das ist wohl, woher diese Ausdrücke komme: man steckt in seiner misslichen Lage fest.

Answer (score 6):

Einige mögliche Übersetzungen:

> to not have a clue what to do
>   to be completely at a loss what to do

"Ein" und "aus" sind keine Präfixe von "wissen". "Weder ein noch aus wissen" ist eine feste Redewendung