# nicht mehr ein noch aus wissen

Tags: meaning

Die roten Matrosen (Klaus Kordons Buch)

> Irgendwo raschelt es. Schnell tritt Helle ein paar Mal mit dem Fuss gegen den Holzverschlag und das Rascheln verstummt. Danach nimmt er den Eimer mit den Kohlen, Besen, Handfeger und Müllschippe, stellt alles vor die Tür des Verschlags, holt die Kerze und schliesst die Lattentür ab. Eigentlich lohnt sich das nicht mehr, es wird ihnen ja niemand einen Zentner Kohlen in den Keller stellen. Wenn er aber nicht abschliesst, muss er das Vorhängeschloss mitnehmen; es könnte geklaut werden. Das ist nicht nur in der Ackerstrasse so. Überall, ***wo die Leute vor Not nicht mehr ein noch aus wissen***, wird geklaut.

I cannot quite understand the meaning of "ein noch aus wissen". How is it working therein?

When I translate it literally: Everywhere where people due to need no longer ...know

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Was bedeutet "vor Sorge weder ein noch aus wissen"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/40883/was-bedeutet-vor-sorge-weder-ein-noch-aus-wissen)

Comment: If I recall correctly, the same question one time in German and one time in English is *not* regarded as "duplicate".

Answer (score 4):

Positiv formuliert wäre es "ein und aus wissen", aber in positiver Form wird es nicht benutzt.

Negativ: "Weder ein noch aus wissen" oder "nicht ein noch aus wissen."

Es ist eine Redewendung, die durch Zerlegung sich nicht erschließt. Sie bedeutet soviel wie keinen Ausweg finden, aber Abwarten ist auch keine Lösung. Ähnlich wie "Es geht nicht vor noch zurück", "Weder gut, noch schlecht", "Nicht hü, nicht hott" (Pferdekommandos für Gehen/Stehen), "Nicht Fisch, nicht Fleisch" - zwei Alternativen oder Gegensätze, die beide nicht passen.

"Nicht **mehr** ein noch aus wissen" heißt, dass es früher besser war.

Comment: Vielleicht sollte man dazusagen, daß die positive Formulierung nicht vorkommt?

Comment: Da die Frage auf englisch gestellt ist (und zwar von einem Benutzer, dessen andere Fragen klar zeigen, dass sein Verständnis der deutschen Sprache recht begrenzt ist!), solltest Du Deine Antwort entweder auf englisch (ja, ich weiß: das lehnst Du aus prinzipiellen Erwägungen ab) oder aber zumindest bilingual schreiben. Wenn Du den gleichen Text auch noch auf englisch hinzufügst, kriegst Du auch ein upvote von mir.

Comment: Gerade der Kommentar unter einer deiner letzten Antworten, dass Google translate zum Lesen benötigt wird, sollte doch beweisen, dass eine deutsche Antwort auf einen englischen OP nicht ausreichend ist. -1

Comment: @infinitezero Meinst du die [Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/55277/36196), die OP akzeptiert hat?

Comment: Jup, die ist es. Wenn "man kann es ja in einen online Übersetzer" eintippen das Argument sein soll, no nii, sitten aloitan vastata suomeksi koska silminnähden missä kielessä kirjoitetaan ei enää oo tärkeää.

Comment: @DavidVogt: Stimmt, wollte ich auch eigentlich erwähnen. Danke.

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf: Was ich soll oder nicht soll, das hast Du mir nicht zu sagen. Wer den obigen Text bis auf die letzte Phrase versteht, wird auch mit meiner Antwort zurechtkommen.

Comment: @infinitezero: Wenn mich mal jmd. fragt, wer einen Text, den man mit cut-and-paste transferieren kann, abtippen würde, werde ich an Dich denken - versprochen!

Comment: @user unknown: Wenn Du so ein Problem mit Argumenten hast, dass Du auf abtippen herumreiten musst, dann ist die Diskussion glaub ich klar entschieden ;) aber wenn wir schon beim Klugscheißen sind: Sofern man nicht auf editieren klickt, wird man wohl eher Copy&Paste nutzen. Übrigens: Wer sich immer da aus "Rache" downvotet (möchte niemanden angucken), versuch's nochmal, das System hat's rückgängig gemacht.

Comment: @infinitezero: Um Probleme mit Argumenten zu haben müsste erst mal ein Argument da sein. Ich weiß nicht was Du mit "sich da aus Rache downvotet" meinst - niemand kann sich, aus welchen Gründen auch immer, downvoten. Meinst Du Dich downvoted? Wo soll ich Dich denn downgevoted haben? Welches Tool, das ich bislang übersehen habe, offenbart denn, von wem ein Downvote stammt? Und wofür sollte ich mich rächen wollen? Und wo soll der Downvote sein - hier ist ja keine Antwort von Dir. Wenn ein Downvote verschwunden ist, dann vielleicht weil sich ein User gelöscht hat? Vorsicht vor Vorurteilen!

Comment: Auf das letzte Argument (siehe Chat) hast Du ja nicht mehr geantwortet. Why do I have a reputation change on my reputation page that says "voting corrected"?
When a single user continually votes (up or down) on many of your posts within a short period of time, the system considers these votes to be invalid and removes them". `Wer sich` sollte `wer auch` heißen, wurde vom Handy verschlimmbessert.

Comment: Siehe Chat? Wo soll ich da was sehen? Welche Frage? Im dt. Chatraum finde ich nichts zu "reputation change". Sind Deine Posts kontinuierlich in kurzer Zeit runtergevoted worden? Und welche Indizien sprechen dafür, dass ich das war? Ich habe ein paar Posts von Dir sicher schon downgevoted, aber ich such nicht danach. Wenn mir eine Antwort nicht usefull erscheint schlag ich zu, egal wer's geschrieben hat. Das ist mein einziges Kriterium. In letzter Zeit komme ich seltener dazu, nur 16 Downvotes in Okt/Nov. Außer die Säuberungen würden unsichtbar aus meiner Rep.-hist gelöscht.

Comment: Ach so. Also kann ich entweder "wo die Leute vor Not nicht mehr ein noch aus wissen" oder "wo die Leute vor Not weder ein noch aus wissen" und die beiden Sätze wären das Gleiche? (Verzeihen sie mir für meine arme Deutsche. Wenn sie ein Fehler finden, korrigieren sie mich, bitte.)

Comment: @davidpolygoth Ja, richtig. Beide Sätze sind richtig und bedeuten dasselbe.

Answer (score 2):

"Weder ein noch aus wissen" is a German expression for describing a desperate situation. To express a situation where it doesn't matter what a subject tries to do, it won't change the situation. Exactly this "try to do something" is the core in "weder ein noch aus".

Answer (score 0):

In general, the expression would be *weder ein noch aus wissen.* It is practically always negated; a positive version would be *ein und aus wissen* but I cannot recall ever having heard that. However, there are several ways in which you can form the negative as you could with the related expressions *vor und zurück* – the consequence is that a Google Ngrams search is conflated by false positives (pun intended) and the graphs don’t show the full picture. (A second problen is that the verb *wissen* is, naturally, not necessarily in its base form and not necessarily at the end of the sentence.)

*Ein und aus* can mean *on and off* or *in and out* and probably a couple of similar pairs depending on the context. In combination with *wissen*, this implies that people absolutely don’t know what to do in a given situation because no reasonable or obvious option will give a positive result.

In the context of your example, the people *die nicht mehr ein noch aus wissen* are probably poor, without job or in very low-paying, hard-working jobs with little perspective for a better life but many mouths to feed.